# How to list which process loaded a specific module?

Tags: process, module, loaded

When a process loads a .dll file and you try to delete this file a messagebox pops up telling you exactly which process is blocking the deletion. How do i replicate that in behaviour in my program? (so i can autoclose that process). There are several versions of that module so just checking all processes for loaded module names isnt enough. Should i SHA the PE header or is there another way to go?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can open up [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), and look at the loaded modules for any process. This will tell you exactly what DLLs are loaded and where they are located on disk.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like. Just click on View, and set the lower pane to DLLs. Then select a process and see the loaded DLLs.

[image]